# how do I export permissions?

Tags: 8

I have changed a bunch of permission for certain roles. How do I export them?  There doesn't seem to be any yaml file created when I do `drush config-export`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Permissions are stored per user role in roles yaml files.

You'll find the permissions for 'Authenticated User', for example, in user.role.authenticated.yml and for 'Administrator' in user.role.administrator.yml